# some Numpy functions return ndarray instead of my subclass

Tags: python, numpy, subclass

I am subclassing Numpy's ndarray class, adding some meta-data and additional methods. I'm  trying to follow the instructions in [this article](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html) and [that one](http://www.scipy.org/Subclasses). However, some Numpy (or Scipy) functions return the base class "ndarray" instead of my custom subclass. Other Numpy functions DO return my subclass, and I don't know what's the reason for the difference. How can I make all the numpy/scipy functions return my subclass? here's what I did:

```
class Signal(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, filename):
        #print "In __new__" #TEMP DEBUG
        ret = np.fromfile(filename, dtype = np.int32)
        ret = ret.view(cls) # convert to my class, i.e. Signal
        ret.parse_filename(filename)
        return ret

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        #print "in __array_finalize__" #TEMP DEBUG
        if obj is None: return # shouldn't actually happen.
        # copy meta-fields from source, if it has them (otherwise put None's)
        self.filename = getattr(obj, "filename", None)
        self.folder = getattr(obj, "folder", None)
        self.label = getattr(obj, "label", None)
        self.date = getattr(obj, "date", None)
        self.time = getattr(obj, "time", None)
        #etc
```

here are some usage examples:

these work as expected -

```
>>> s = Signal(filename)
>>> s2 = s[10:20]
>>> type (s2)
<class '__main__.Signal'>
>>> s3 = s + 17
>>> type (s3)
<class '__main__.Signal'>
>>> s4 = np.sqrt(s)
>>> type(s4)
<class '__main__.Signal'>
```

however, what about these?

```
>>> s5 = log10(s)
>>> type(s5)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> s6 = np.fft.fft(s)
>>> type(s6)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

looking into the code of `fft` and `log10` I can see that they use `asarray()`, which strips the subclass and returns an ndarray, explaining the behavior. Therefore, my question isn't "why, technically, this happens" but more a design question - how should I write my code so this doesn't happen?

p.s. I'm a newbie both at Python and here on Stack Overflow, so please excuse any obvious mistakes or inappropriateness...

thanks,
Guy.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about `fft`, but `np.log10` is a [ufunc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html). The following page explains how the output type of a ufunc is determined: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#output-type-determination

It wouldn't surprise me if `fft` always returned an `ndarray` though (I haven't looked at the source code, but the FFT clearly doesn't fit the definition of a ufunc). If that's the case, you can always write your own wrapper and call that instead.

Comment: To expand on this, you need to implement the `__array_wrap__` method in your subclass.  See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html#array-wrap-for-ufuncs .

Comment: ok, I just discovered that there's a difference between Numpy's `log10()` and Scipy's `log10()`... the numpy one is well behaved ufunc, returning my subclass as implemented above (without `__array_wrap__` by the way). The scipy `log10` returns a base class though. anyone knows what's the rationale behind this? which log10 should I use...? any difference in actual numerical output? how about other functions? what's the reason for the duplicates anyway...?

Comment: Stephen, can you elaborate on why do I need to implement `__array_wrap__`, now that I notice that numpy functions actually DO return my subclass, only Scipy's don't (see my comment above)? will it help with Scipy's functions? any problem with what I did in my code above, considering that I didn't implement `__array_wrap__`?

Comment: @tinkerer: I've been wondering about the apparent duplication between numpy and scipy myself. I've just posted a question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200910/relationship-between-scipy-and-numpy