# Relationship between SciPy and NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

SciPy appears to provide most (but not all [1]) of NumPy's functions in its own namespace. In other words, if there's a function named `numpy.foo`, there's almost certainly a `scipy.foo`. Most of the time, the two appear to be exactly the same, oftentimes even pointing to the same function object.

Sometimes, they're different. To give an example that came up recently:

- `numpy.log10` is a [ufunc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) that returns NaNs for negative arguments;
- `scipy.log10` returns complex values for negative arguments and doesn't appear to be a ufunc.

The same can be said about `log`, `log2` and `logn`, but not about `log1p` [2].

On the other hand, `numpy.exp` and `scipy.exp` appear to be different names for the same ufunc. This is also true of `scipy.log1p` and `numpy.log1p`.

Another example is `numpy.linalg.solve` vs `scipy.linalg.solve`. They're similar, but the latter offers some additional features over the former.

Why the apparent duplication? If this is meant to be a wholesale import of `numpy` into the `scipy` namespace, why the subtle differences in behaviour and the missing functions? Is there some overarching logic that would help clear up the confusion?

[1] `numpy.min`, `numpy.max`, `numpy.abs` and a few others have no counterparts in the `scipy` namespace.

[2] Tested using NumPy 1.5.1 and SciPy 0.9.0rc2.

Comment: I read in the answers that `all of those functions are available without additionally importing Numpy` because `the intention is for users not to have to know the distinction between the scipy and numpy namespaces`. Now I wonder, because I follow the posts about numpy and scipy a bit and use it myself. And I almost always see numpy being imported seperately (as np). So they failed?

Comment: there's some differences between scipy and numpy is in FFT stuff, i once got bitten by an issue that eventually tracked down to scipy and numpy's version of rfft defined differently

Comment: The FFTs of SciPy and NumPy are different. SciPy uses the Fortran library FFTPACK, hence the name scipy.fftpack. NumPy uses a C library called fftpack_lite; it has fewer functions and only supports double precision in NumPy. Enthought inc. has patched their numpy.fft to use Intel MKL for FFTs instead of fftpack_lite.

Comment: NumPy was originally named scipy.core. NumPy and SciPy are closely related projects. The main reason for the separation is to ensure that the array library (NumPy) is lean and mean, as the bulk of SciPy is not always needed. Also, there was as decision among scientists to retire the array packages numeric (MIT) and numarray (NASA) in favor of scipy.core, and thus it got the name NumPy. SciPy has still not reached 1.0, whereas NumPy is currently released as 1.8.1. NumPy has some facilities for FFT and linear algebra, but not as extensive as SciPy.

Comment: @SturlaMolden good to know about Enthought, do you know if Anaconda optimizes both or just numpy?

Comment: @dashesy AFAIK, Anaconda does not use MKL for FFTs. If I am not mistaken their MKL add-on only optimises linear algebra operations (BLAS and LAPACK).

Comment: Note: as of SciPy 1.4.0 "Support for NumPy functions exposed via the root SciPy namespace is deprecated
and will be removed in 2.0.0. For example, if you use scipy.rand or
scipy.diag, you should change your code to directly use
numpy.random.default_rng or numpy.diag, respectively.
They remain available in the currently continuing Scipy 1.x release series." https://github.com/scipy/scipy/releases/tag/v1.4.0

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Last time I checked it, the scipy `__init__` method executes a

```
from numpy import *
```

so that the whole numpy namespace is included into scipy when the scipy module is imported.

The `log10` behavior you are describing is interesting, because *both* versions are coming from numpy. One is a `ufunc`, the other is a `numpy.lib` function. Why scipy is preferring the library function over the `ufunc`, I don't know off the top of my head.

---

EDIT: In fact, I can answer the `log10` question. Looking in the scipy `__init__` method I see this:

```
# Import numpy symbols to scipy name space
import numpy as _num
from numpy import oldnumeric
from numpy import *
from numpy.random import rand, randn
from numpy.fft import fft, ifft
from numpy.lib.scimath import *
```

The `log10` function you get in scipy comes from `numpy.lib.scimath`. Looking at that code, it says:

```
"""
Wrapper functions to more user-friendly calling of certain math functions
whose output data-type is different than the input data-type in certain
domains of the input.

For example, for functions like log() with branch cuts, the versions in this
module provide the mathematically valid answers in the complex plane:

>>> import math
>>> from numpy.lib import scimath
>>> scimath.log(-math.exp(1)) == (1+1j*math.pi)
True

Similarly, sqrt(), other base logarithms, power() and trig functions are
correctly handled.  See their respective docstrings for specific examples.
"""
```

It seems that module overlays the base numpy ufuncs for `sqrt`, `log`, `log2`, `logn`, `log10`, `power`, `arccos`, `arcsin`, and `arctanh`. That explains the behavior you are seeing. The underlying design reason why it is done like that is probably buried in a mailing list post somewhere.

Comment: After working full time with these packages for a while, here's the feeling I get about it: NumPy is meant to be a library for numerical arrays, to be used by anybody needing such an object in Python. SciPy is meant to be a library for scientists/engineers, so it aims for more rigourous theorethical mathematics (thus including complex number version of log10 and the like). The main confusion comes from the fact that NumPy retains many old sub-modules (which should have gone into Scipy) that were included at the time when the demarcation between SciPy/NumPy wasn't as clear as it is today.

Comment: @PhilMacKay Hi Phil, I read this and your other post specific to this numpy/scipy question from 2013. My question is if your opinion is still current, as stated well in your comment above? i see the poster said there are some non-equivalents in scipy and lists abs, max and min as examples, but I do understand that abs is just an alias for numpy.absolute and there is a scipy.absolute, scipy.maximum and scipy.minimum. So in your experience up to now have you ever needed to import numpy if you are already in need of scipy?

Comment: @PhilMacKay It seems to be that the general consensus is to use the submodule libraries of SciPy for their relevant use cases, and then for the core NumPy operations to import NumPy specifically  (instead of the top level of SciPy which you would otherwise need to import). For some reason this is stated by others as well as the SciPy documentation itself as better coding practice and I am trying to understand why it would matter. I assume it is because it is a matter of convention and therefore readability. What is your current opinion?

Comment: @DanBoschen As of November 2018, I still stand by my comment above. Importing SciPy when only NumPy is needed might be a bit overkill. On the other hand, NumPy is imported when SciPy is loaded, so there is no need to import NumPy in addition to SciPy. Off course, there are good arguments for following the documentation, so feel free to do what is most relevant in your own situation.

Comment: @PhilMacKay Thanks for your input. Having thought it through my guess why it is suggested to import numpy (even though everything can be done in scipy) is a matter of convention and therefore readability for shared code. If all numpy specific code is tied to the numpy library specifically, it can also be more easily broken off from being tied into the larger scipy library which includes a lot more that may not always be needed. That said my thought (for my own approach) is to import numpy and then NOT import the top level scipy but only import the scipy subpackages as needed.

Comment: The one sqrt(-1) detail does annoy me, in that you need to import numpy.emath if you want to stay within the numpy package and handle that type of mathematics.

Answer (score 59):

From the SciPy Reference Guide:

> ... all of the Numpy functions have
>   been subsumed into the `scipy`
>   namespace so that all of those
>   functions are available without
>   additionally importing Numpy.

The intention is for users not to have to know the distinction between the `scipy` and `numpy` namespaces, though apparently you've found an exception.

Answer (score 56):

It seems from the [SciPy FAQ](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/faq.html#id17) that some functions from NumPy are here for historical reasons while it should
only be in SciPy:

> ### What is the difference between NumPy and SciPy?
>
> In an ideal world, NumPy would contain nothing but the array data type and
>   the most  basic operations: indexing, sorting, reshaping, basic
>   elementwise functions, et cetera. All numerical code would reside in
>   SciPy. However, one of NumPy’s important goals is compatibility, so NumPy
>   tries to retain all features supported by either of its predecessors. Thus
>   NumPy contains some linear algebra functions, even though these more
>   properly belong in SciPy. In any case, SciPy contains more fully-featured
>   versions of the linear algebra modules, as well as many other numerical
>   algorithms. If you are doing scientific computing with python, you should
>   probably install both NumPy and SciPy. Most new features belong in SciPy
>   rather than NumPy.

That explains why `scipy.linalg.solve` offers some additional features over `numpy.linalg.solve`.

I did not see the answer of SethMMorton to the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10767644/1517918)

Answer (score 13):

There is a short comment at the end of the [introduction to SciPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/general.html) documentation:

> Another useful command is`source`. When given a function written in Python as an argument, it  prints out a listing of the source code for that function. This can be helpful in learning  about an algorithm or understanding exactly what a function is 
>   doing with its arguments. Also don’t forget about the Python command dir which can be 
>   used to look at the namespace of a module or package.

I think this will allow someone with enough knowledge of all the packages involved to pick apart exactly what the differences are between *some* scipy and numpy functions (it didn't help me with the log10 question at all). I definitely don't have that knowledge but `source` does indicate that `scipy.linalg.solve` and `numpy.linalg.solve` interact with lapack in different ways;

```
Python 2.4.3 (#1, May  5 2011, 18:44:23) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)] on linux2
>>> import scipy
>>> import scipy.linalg
>>> import numpy
>>> scipy.source(scipy.linalg.solve)
In file: /usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/scipy/linalg/basic.py

def solve(a, b, sym_pos=0, lower=0, overwrite_a=0, overwrite_b=0,
          debug = 0):
    """ solve(a, b, sym_pos=0, lower=0, overwrite_a=0, overwrite_b=0) -> x

    Solve a linear system of equations a * x = b for x.

    Inputs:

      a -- An N x N matrix.
      b -- An N x nrhs matrix or N vector.
      sym_pos -- Assume a is symmetric and positive definite.
      lower -- Assume a is lower triangular, otherwise upper one.
               Only used if sym_pos is true.
      overwrite_y - Discard data in y, where y is a or b.

    Outputs:

      x -- The solution to the system a * x = b
    """
    a1, b1 = map(asarray_chkfinite,(a,b))
    if len(a1.shape) != 2 or a1.shape[0] != a1.shape[1]:
        raise ValueError, 'expected square matrix'
    if a1.shape[0] != b1.shape[0]:
        raise ValueError, 'incompatible dimensions'
    overwrite_a = overwrite_a or (a1 is not a and not hasattr(a,'__array__'))
    overwrite_b = overwrite_b or (b1 is not b and not hasattr(b,'__array__'))
    if debug:
        print 'solve:overwrite_a=',overwrite_a
        print 'solve:overwrite_b=',overwrite_b
    if sym_pos:
        posv, = get_lapack_funcs(('posv',),(a1,b1))
        c,x,info = posv(a1,b1,
                        lower = lower,
                        overwrite_a=overwrite_a,
                        overwrite_b=overwrite_b)
    else:
        gesv, = get_lapack_funcs(('gesv',),(a1,b1))
        lu,piv,x,info = gesv(a1,b1,
                             overwrite_a=overwrite_a,
                             overwrite_b=overwrite_b)

    if info==0:
        return x
    if info>0:
        raise LinAlgError, "singular matrix"
    raise ValueError,\
          'illegal value in %-th argument of internal gesv|posv'%(-info)

>>> scipy.source(numpy.linalg.solve)
In file: /usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py

def solve(a, b):
    """
    Solve the equation ``a x = b`` for ``x``.

    Parameters
    ----------
    a : array_like, shape (M, M)
        Input equation coefficients.
    b : array_like, shape (M,)
        Equation target values.

    Returns
    -------
    x : array, shape (M,)

    Raises
    ------
    LinAlgError
        If `a` is singular or not square.

    Examples
    --------
    Solve the system of equations ``3 * x0 + x1 = 9`` and ``x0 + 2 * x1 = 8``:

    >>> a = np.array([[3,1], [1,2]])
    >>> b = np.array([9,8])
    >>> x = np.linalg.solve(a, b)
    >>> x
    array([ 2.,  3.])

    Check that the solution is correct:

    >>> (np.dot(a, x) == b).all()
    True

    """
    a, _ = _makearray(a)
    b, wrap = _makearray(b)
    one_eq = len(b.shape) == 1
    if one_eq:
        b = b[:, newaxis]
    _assertRank2(a, b)
    _assertSquareness(a)
    n_eq = a.shape[0]
    n_rhs = b.shape[1]
    if n_eq != b.shape[0]:
        raise LinAlgError, 'Incompatible dimensions'
    t, result_t = _commonType(a, b)
#    lapack_routine = _findLapackRoutine('gesv', t)
    if isComplexType(t):
        lapack_routine = lapack_lite.zgesv
    else:
        lapack_routine = lapack_lite.dgesv
    a, b = _fastCopyAndTranspose(t, a, b)
    pivots = zeros(n_eq, fortran_int)
    results = lapack_routine(n_eq, n_rhs, a, n_eq, pivots, b, n_eq, 0)
    if results['info'] > 0:
        raise LinAlgError, 'Singular matrix'
    if one_eq:
        return wrap(b.ravel().astype(result_t))
    else:
        return wrap(b.transpose().astype(result_t))
```

This is also my first post so if I should change something here please let me know.

Comment: The underlying wrappers are very different. NumPy uses a thin layer written in C. SciPy uses a layer autogenerated by f2py. SciPy always linkes with an external LAPACK library. NumPy uses has its own f2c'd lapack_lite in case an external LAPACK is not found.

Answer (score 8):

From Wikipedia ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy#History ):

> The Numeric code was adapted to make
>   it more maintainable and flexible
>   enough to implement the novel features
>   of Numarray. This new project was part
>   of SciPy. To avoid installing a whole
>   package just to get an array object,
>   this new package was separated and
>   called NumPy.

`scipy` depends on `numpy` and imports many `numpy` functions into its namespace for convenience.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding the linalg package - the scipy functions will call lapack and blas, which are available in highly optimised versions on many platforms and offer very good performance, particularly for operations on reasonably large dense matrices.  On the other hand, they are not easy libraries to compile, requiring a fortran compiler and many platform specific tweaks to get full performance. Therefore, numpy provides simple implementations of many common linear algebra functions which are often good enough for many purposes.

Comment: numpy 1.10 has a nice module `dual`: "This module should be used for functions both in numpy and scipy if
 you want to use the numpy version if available but the scipy version
 otherwise."
 Usage  --- `from numpy.dual import fft, inv`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the [SciPy FAQ](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/faq.html#what-is-the-difference-between-numpy-and-scipy) describing the duplication is mainly for backwards compatibility, it is further clarified in the [NumPy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.dual.html) to say that

> **Optionally SciPy-accelerated routines (numpy.dual)**
>
> Aliases for functions which may be accelerated by Scipy.
>
> SciPy can be built to use accelerated or otherwise improved libraries
>   for FFTs, linear algebra, and special functions. This module allows
>   developers to transparently support these accelerated functions when
>   SciPy is available but still support users who have only installed
>   NumPy.

For brevity, these are:

- Linear algebra
- FFT
- The Modified Bessel function of the first kind, order 0

Also, from the [SciPy Tutorial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/basic.html):

> The top level of SciPy also contains functions from NumPy and
>   numpy.lib.scimath. However, it is better to use them directly from the
>   NumPy module instead.

So, for new applications, you should prefer the NumPy version of the array operations that are duplicated in the top level of SciPy. For the domains listed above, you should prefer those in SciPy and check backward compatibility if necessary in NumPy.

In my personal experience, most of the array functions I use exist in the top level of NumPy (except for `random`). However, all the domain specific routines exist in subpackages of SciPy, so I rarely use anything from the top level of SciPy.

Answer (score 1):

From Lectures on '[Quantitative Economics](https://lectures.quantecon.org/py/scipy.html#scipy-versus-numpy)'

SciPy is a package that contains various tools that are built on top of NumPy, using its array data type and related functionality

In fact, when we import SciPy we also get NumPy, as can be seen from the SciPy initialization file

```
# Import numpy symbols to scipy name space
import numpy as _num
linalg = None
from numpy import *
from numpy.random import rand, randn
from numpy.fft import fft, ifft
from numpy.lib.scimath import *

__all__  = []
__all__ += _num.__all__
__all__ += ['randn', 'rand', 'fft', 'ifft']

del _num
# Remove the linalg imported from numpy so that the scipy.linalg package can be
# imported.
del linalg
__all__.remove('linalg')
```

However, it’s more common and better practice to use NumPy functionality explicitly

```
import numpy as np

a = np.identity(3)
```

What is useful in SciPy is the functionality in its subpackages

- scipy.optimize, scipy.integrate, scipy.stats, etc.

Comment: I see your comment that it is better practice to use NumPy functionality explicitly, and I see this echoed elsewhere including in the SciPy tutorial, but why is this better practice? No one seems to answer that. If you are already importing SciPy and it includes the NumPy functionality, why is it better to still import NumPy? Is it that when we import a subpackage in SciPy, we are NOT importing the top level, and therefore instead of taking the step to import SciPy specifically, we should just import Numpy for those core array processing functions?