# Official abbreviation for: import scipy as sp/sc

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I've seen both:

```
import scipy as sp
```

and:

```
import scipy as sc
```

Is there an official preference listed anywhere?

For example, in the [Introduction of the Scipy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/general.html), it is recommended to

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

but a similar abbreviation is not offered for the Scipy package.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528981/scipy-numpy-import-guideline?rq=1), `sp` is recommended, but the link to the Scipy docs doesn't actually specify `sp` over `sc`.

Comment: see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/api.html#guidelines-for-importing-functions-from-scipy

Comment: Oh, so the advice in the linked questions is actually misleading. You basically never want to ``import scipy as sp``. You just want to `from scipy import integrate`. This is interesting, since it seems like there could be potential conflicts between the, somewhat generically, titled scipy submodules.

Comment: @DanHickstein: you could use `import scipy.integrate as SI` or some such unique identifier to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SciPy maintainer here.

Before SciPy 1.9, we recommended people to not import the main namespace (`import scipy`) because this would recursively import everything leading to long import time.

Now we have a lazy loading mechanism which does not incur any performance penalty. So you can do `import scipy` and modules are only loaded when you use them.

To answer the OP, we do not have a recommended way to import SciPy. There are strong opinions among maintainers. Some maintainers advocate for never using aliases while other would welcome one.

My personal take is that, while the project does not recommend the use of an alias, if people are still going to use one, it would be best if everyone doing so would use the same. `sp` seems to be more used and libraries like NetworkX and Scikit-Image use this convention internally.

See the updated doc:
https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/index.html#guidelines-for-importing-functions-from-scipy

Comment: So, what I'm hearing is that if we all keep using "import scipy as sp", it will officially make it into the scipy docs as the official recommendation :).

Comment: haha I buy you a coffee if that happens ;)

Answer (score 57):

EDIT: As of version 1.9, scipy has changed so that `import scipy` now allows access to the modules but only actually loads them when they are used. Please refer to the answer from tupui below (and upvote that answer to make it the top one!). For historical purposes, here is my answer from 2016:

The "official" answer, according to the [Scipy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/api.html#guidelines-for-importing-functions-from-scipy), is that there is really no reason to ever

```
import scipy
```

since all of the interesting functions in Scipy are actually located in the submodules, which are not automatically imported. Therefore, the recommended method is to use

```
from scipy import fftpack
from scipy import integrate
```

then, functions can be called with

```
fftpack.fft()
```

Personally, I always use

```
import scipy.fftpack
```

and live with the slightly longer function call

```
scipy.fftpack.fft(data)
```

This way I know where the functions are coming from.

Comment: On the other hand, fully qualified names may be preferable in longer scripts. And then a short-hand for `scipy` can be useful. Something like `import scipy as sp` followed by `import scipy.fft` will allow to use in the code: `sp.fft`.

Comment: The situation changed a bit recently, see my answer bellow https://stackoverflow.com/a/76762035/6522112 It's now okay to do `import scipy` and this would not incur any performance issue vs `import scipy.fft`. Note that `fftpack` is legacy and you should move to `scipy.fft`

Answer (score 14):

As *cel* pointed out, the [API documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/index.html) recommends to not `import scipy`, but to import specific modules from `scipy`:

> The scipy namespace itself only contains functions imported from numpy. These functions still exist for backwards compatibility, but should be imported from numpy directly.

Therefore, importing only the `scipy` base package does only provide `numpy` content, which could be imported from numpy directly.

If somebody still wants the main package, `sp` for **S**ci**p**y would be convenient as `np` usially is used for **N**um**P**y.

Comment: In the same URL, scipy recommends `import scipy.io as spio` for io. So, `sp` makes sense.

Comment: `sp` for `scipy` conflicts with common use of `sp` for `sympy`.

Answer (score 3):

Based on github repositories the most commonly used is:

import scipy as sp

[Github usage stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqZkB.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31888011)

Comment: That total seems way too low. Has it excluded the tens of thousands that don't use `as`?