# RuntimeError: Scipy not found

Tags: python

Thanks in advance for your help
I was trying to install this program in Python, code below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""Made by Luuk Visser (UL/TUD), with tweaks by Brett Morris (NASA GSFC/UMD)"""

import os
import sys
import shutil
import subprocess
import atexit
import urllib2


def internet_on():
    refURL = 'http://www.google.com'
    try:
        response=urllib2.urlopen(refURL,timeout=1)
        return True
    except urllib2.URLError as err: pass
    return False

# Checking for all required packages and if these are recent enough
minimum_numpy_version = "1.6"
minimum_matplotlib_version = "1.0"
minimum_pyfits_version = "3.1.0" # lower versions may work (not tested)
minimum_scipy_version = "0.10" # lower versions may work (not tested)
minimum_wxpython_version = "2.0" # lower versions may work (not tested)
sysplatform = sys.platform

if not hasattr(sys, 'real_prefix'):
    # Currently only Python 2.7.x is supported
    if sys.version_info[:2] != (2, 7):
        raise RuntimeError("must use python 2.7.x")

    if not internet_on():
        raise RuntimeError("Must be connected to the internet to complete "\
                        "install. Please connect to the internet and start "\
                        "the install again.")

    # Check if the package dependancies/requirements are fulfilled
    try:
        from setuptools import setup
    except:
        raise RuntimeError("Setuptools not found, setup cannot continue without it")

    try:
        import numpy as np
    except:
        raise RuntimeError("Numpy not found")
    if np.__version__ < minimum_numpy_version:
        print("*Error*: NumPy version is lower than needed: %s < %s" %
              (np.__version__, minimum_numpy_version))
        sys.exit(1)

    try:
        import scipy
    except:
        raise RuntimeError("Scipy not found")
    if scipy.__version__ < minimum_scipy_version:
        print("*Error*: Scipy version is lower than needed: %s < %s" %
              (scipy.__version__, minimum_scipy_version))
        sys.exit(1)  

    try:
        import matplotlib
    except:
        raise RuntimeError("matplotlib not found")
    if matplotlib.__version__ < minimum_matplotlib_version:
        print("*Error*: matplotlib version is lower than needed: %s < %s" %
              (matplotlib.__version__, minimum_matplotlib_version))
        sys.exit(1)

    try:
        import pyfits
    except:
        raise RuntimeError("PyFITS not found")
    if pyfits.__version__ < minimum_pyfits_version:
        print("*Error*: PyFITS version is lower than needed: %s < %s" %
              (pyfits.__version__, minimum_pyfits_version))
        sys.exit(1)  

    try:
        if sysplatform == 'darwin' or 'linux2':
             import wx
        else:
             """ (assuming in this case that sysplatform == 'win32' """
             import wxPython
    except:
        raise RuntimeError("wxPython not found")
    if wx.__version__ < minimum_wxpython_version:
        print("*Error*: wxPython version is lower than needed: %s < %s" %
              (wx.__version__, minimum_wxpython_version))
        sys.exit(1)  
else: 
    from setuptools import setup

# Walk through the subdirs and add all non-python scripts to MANIFEST.in
def create_manifest():    
    print 'creating manifest.in'
    matches = []
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('oscaar'):
        if ('.git' in str(root)) == False:
            for filename in filenames:
                if filename.endswith(('.py', '.pyc')) == False:
                  matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('docs'):
        if ('.git' in str(root)) == False:
            for filename in filenames:
                if filename.endswith(('.py', '.pyc')) == False:
                  matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    # Manually add extra files from the top-level directory
    matches.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'post_setup.py'))
    matches.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'INSTALL.txt'))
    matches.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'LICENSE.txt'))

    with open('MANIFEST.in', 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(("include %s\n" % l.replace(' ','?') for l in matches))

# To remove the manifest file after installation
def delete_manifest():
    if os.path.exists('MANIFEST.in'):
        os.remove('MANIFEST.in')

# Create list for Python scripts directories to include
def get_packages():
    print 'searching for packages'
    matches = []
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('oscaar'):
        if ('.git' in str(root)) == False:
            for filename in filenames:
                if filename.endswith(('.py', '.pyc')) == True:
                    matches.append(root)
    matches = list(set(matches))
    return matches

def del_dir(dirname):
    if os.path.exists(dirname):
        shutil.rmtree(dirname)

# The setup configuration for installing OSCAAR


def setup_package():
    create_manifest()
    list = ['Numpy>=1.6','Scipy>=0.1','pyfits>=3.1','pyephem>=3.7',\
         'matplotlib>=1.2.1']
    setup(
        name = "OSCAAR",
        version = "2.0beta",
        author = "Core Developer: Brett M. Morris. Contributors: "+\
                      "Daniel Galdi, Dharmatej Mikkilineni, Luuk Visser",
        author_email = "oscaarteam@gmail.com",
        description = ("oscaar is an open source project aimed at "+\
                      "helping you begin to study transiting extrasolar "+\
                      "planets with differential photometry."),
        license = 'LICENSE.txt',
        keywords = "oscaar transit astronomy photometry exoplanets",
        url = "https://github.com/OSCAAR/OSCAAR/wiki",
        packages=get_packages(),
        include_package_data = True,
        zip_safe = False,
        long_description=open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(\
                      os.path.abspath(__file__)),'README')).read(),
        download_url='https://github.com/OSCAAR/OSCAAR/archive/master.zip',
         install_requires=list,
         dependency_links = ['https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/'+\
                            'matplotlib/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.2.1/'+\
                            'matplotlib-1.2.1.tar.gz'],
        classifiers=[
          'Development Status :: 4 - Beta',
          'Intended Audience :: Science/Research',
          'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
          'Operating System :: OS Independent',
          'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
          'Programming Language :: C',
          'Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Astronomy',
          'Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Physics'
      ],
    )


# At exit delete temporary files, and run post setup script if 
# argument is 'install'
def to_do_at_exit():
    delete_manifest()
    #del_dir('build')
    #del_dir('OSCAAR.egg-info')

    if 'install' in sys.argv: 
        del_dir('dist')

        'Installation finished. Starting DS9 downloader and compile C\n'
        subprocess.check_call(['python', 'post_setup.py',sys.argv[-1]])

#Set function to be executed at exit of code (when script is finished)
atexit.register(to_do_at_exit)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup_package()
```

As a guide I have to execute this code:

```
python setup.py install
```

The problem is that I get this error:

```
 File "setup.py", line 57, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("Scipy not found")
RuntimeError: Scipy not found
```

I do not understand what the problem is and I would appreciate it if you helped me to figure out how to solve this problem, I thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try to install it? `pip install scipy`

Comment: Yes, I've tried it but it always gives me the same error

Comment: @GionataDonati whats the console output when using `pip install scipy` ?

Comment: pip install scipy
Collecting scipy
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/d6/3eac96ffcf7cbeb37ed72982cf3fdd3138472cb04ab32cdce1f444d765f2/scipy-1.1.0-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (16.8MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 16.8MB 465kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from scipy) (1.9.1)
Installing collected packages: scipy
Successfully installed scipy-1.1.0

Comment: @TheFool Sorry for the formatting

Comment: well this is not solving the issue but you might have a read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36014733/official-abbreviation-for-import-scipy-as-sp-sc they say allmost everytime u use scipy you use some stuff from its modules which are not automaticly imported. So maybe try `from scipy import *needed_stuff*`

Comment: @GionataDonati What is the python version you have run?

Comment: @CeylanB. Good questions I didnt think of it but scipy only gets installed for 2.7 here as it seems