# module 'scipy' has no attribute 'norm'

Tags: python, scipy

I am new to python and I am trying to understand why I am not being able to graph a plot. First I imported all of the libraries I have been using in the program:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import scipy as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

And when I run the following code:

```
sns.distplot(financials.residual,kde=False,fit=stats.norm)
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute 'norm'
```

I believe it might be because I am not importing the correct module from spicy but I can't find the way to get it right.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`norm` is in `scipy.stats`, not in `scipy`.
Importing "scipy as stats" simply imports scipy and renames it to stats, it doesn't import the stats submodule inside scipy.

do

```
from scipy.stats import norm
```

like on the [official website example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html)

or

```
from scipy import stats
stats.norm(...)
```

Note:
when "importing something as somethingelse", be careful to not shadow other names and if possible follow conventions (like `import numpy as np`).

For scipy, as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36015040/11579184) answer, the convention is to never "`import scipy as ...`" since all the interesting functions in scipy are actually located in the submodules, which are not automatically imported.

Answer (score 3):

Do not `import scipy as stats`. There is a library module called `stats`. By renaming `scipy`, you shadow the original `stats` module and prevent 
Python from accessing it. Then `stats.norm` essentially becomes `scipy.norm`, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's see how to make proper use of import:

**1)Importing a Library:**
The first method is to import the library directly and access the modules under it with a '.'. This is illustrated here:

```
import pandas
import numpy
pandas.read_csv('helloworld.csv')
```

pandas is a library and read_csv is a module inside it.

**2)Importing the module directly**
The second method is to import the module directly as follows:

```
from pandas import read_csv
read_csv('helloworld.csv')
```

Use this method when you know that you'll only be using read_csv module of pandas and not any other module under it.

**3)Importing all the modules under a library**

```
from pandas import *
```

This will import all the modules under the pandas library and you can use them directly.

Now coming to your question:

The norm function is present inside the stats module of scipy. When you use `as`, you're giving an alias for the library/module inside your code. So instead try this method

```
from scipy.stats import norm
norm(...)
```

or

```
from scipy import stats
stats.norm(..)
```

Hope this helps!