# What is the difference between numpy.polyfit and scipy.polyfit?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I came to know both numpy and scipy have polyfit function and visited here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html

Why does scipy.org have a page about numpy.polyfit? Are numpy.polyfit and scipy.polyfit the same? If not, which one should I use?

Comment: *"What is the difference...?"*  Nothing.  They are *exactly* the same object.  The top-level scipy namespace includes the top-level numpy names.  (I'm sure this question, or something very similar with the same answer, has been asked before.)

Comment: *"... which one should I use?"*  Use `numpy.polyfit`.  More than one developer considers the dumping of the numpy names into the scipy namespace a mistake.  Perhaps there were good reasons back when it was done, but now it just leads to confusion and questions like this one.

Comment: Here's a relevant stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200910/relationship-between-scipy-and-numpy/6201054.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`polyfit` is not implemented by scipy.  [There is a line](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/__init__.py#L69) in `scipy.__init__` which does

```
from numpy import *
```

and this is how the name is pulled into scipy's namespace.

It does not make any difference which you use, because they are literally the same object in memory:

```
>>> import scipy
>>> import numpy
>>> scipy.polyfit is numpy.polyfit
True
```

You may as well cut out the middleman and use the one from `numpy`.