# Numpy and Scipy Difference

Tags: python, scipy

What is the difference between scipy and numpy? For example I didnt understand difference between scipy.linalg.lstsq and numpy.linalg.lstsq.
Can you explain it with example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relationship between SciPy and NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200910/relationship-between-scipy-and-numpy)

Comment: The essential differences should be obvious from the docs.  `scipy` is a diverse collections of modules all built on `numpy`.  There are some duplicates, especially in `linalg`, or near duplicates.  I suspect`lstsq` has been discussed in other SO questions.  Better yet, tell us what you deduced from the docs!

Answer (score 1):

From afar `numpy` and `scipy` are two different libraries implemented by different people. They have different goals : `numpy` is oriented towards general computation (how to handle arrays, common operations on them...) whereas `scipy` is oriented towards scientific computing (inverting matrices etc...)

In practice, in turns out that the people developing `numpy` and `scipy` are the same, so the reality is a bit more complex than this, but the idea stays the same.

That being said, it is possible that they implement similar functions, because they could be described both as `general computation` or `scientific computation`. Since the people who coded `scipy` and `numpy` are not the same, they do not necessarily communicate with each other and this is why some functions can be implmented in both libraries.

Comment: The two packages are from the same people. Numpy used to be named scipy.core

Comment: Oh, my bad, thank you for your comment, I am going to modify the answer