# Keeping a numpy ndarray subclass as the return value during a transformation. Safe to set __array_priority__?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, subclass

I'm trying to subclass `numpy`'s `ndarray` class, and have had some luck. The behavior that I would like is nearly exactly the same as the [example](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html#slightly-more-realistic-example-attribute-added-to-existing-array) given in the documentation. I want to add a parameter `name` to the array (which I use to keep track of where the data originally came from).

```
class Template(np.ndarray):
    """A subclass of numpy's n dimensional array that allows for a
    reference back to the name of the template it came from.
    """
    def __new__(cls, input_array, name=None):
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        obj.name = name
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None: return
        self.name = getattr(obj, 'name', None)
```

This works, except that, like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190859/some-numpy-functions-return-ndarray-instead-of-my-subclass), **I want any transformation involving my subclass to return another instance of my subclass**.

Sometimes numpy functions do return an instance of `Template`:

```
>>> a = Template(np.array([[1,2,3], [2,4,6]], name='from here')
>>> np.dot(a, np.array([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]))
Template([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6]])
```

However, sometimes they don't:

```
>>> np.dot(np.array([[1,0],[0,1]]), a)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6]])
```

In the question I linked to above, it was suggested that the OP should override the `__wrap_array__` method for the subclass. However, I don't see any justification in this. In some situations, I'm getting my expected behavior with the default `__array_wrap__`. [The docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html#array-wrap-for-ufuncs) seem to suggest that I'm running into a situation where it's the other argument's `__array_wrap__` method being called because of a higher `__array_priority__` value:

> Note that the ufunc (`np.add`) has called the `__array_wrap__` method of
>   the input with the highest `__array_priority__` value

So my question has a couple related parts. First: **can I set the `__array_priority__` attribute of my subclass such that its `__array_wrap__` will always be called?** Second: **Is this the best/easiest way to go about achieving my desired behavior?**

Answer (score 0):

When two objects have the same __array_priority__:

```
>>> np.array([[1,0],[0,1]]).__array_priority__
0.0
>>> a.__array_priority__
0.0
```

And only one object's methods can be used, the tie is resolved by using the first array's/object's methods. (In your case __array_wrap__)

From the question it seems like your class' methods should always be preferred, since they are the same (through inheritance) or overridden.

So I would just crank up the __array_priority__.

```
class Template(np.ndarray):
    __array_priority__ = 1.0 (Or whichever value is high enough)
    ...
```

After you do this no matter where the template object is in a calculation. It's  methods will be preferred over standard arrays' methods.