# Numpy apply_along_axis not returning ndarray subclass

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have an `ndarray` subclass, with `__array_wrap__` properly implemented, `np.apply_along_axis` isn't returning instances of my subclass, but rather `ndarrays`. The code below replicates my problem:

```
import numpy as np

class MySubClass(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(cls, input_array, info=None):
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        obj.info = info
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None: return
        self.info = getattr(obj, 'info', None)

    def __array_wrap__(self, out_arr, context=None):
        return np.ndarray.__array_wrap__(self, out_arr, context)

sample_ndarray = np.array([[0,5],[2.1,0]]) 
sample_subclass = MySubClass(sample_ndarray, info="Hi Stack Overflow")

# Find the smallest positive (>0) number along the first axis
min_positive = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.min(np.extract(x>0,x)),
                                   0, sample_subclass)

# No more info
print hasattr(min_positive, 'info')
# Not a subclass
print isinstance(min_positive, MySubClass)
# Is an ndarray
print isinstance(min_positive, np.ndarray)
```

The most relevant question I could find was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190859/some-numpy-functions-return-ndarray-instead-of-my-subclass) but the consensus there appears to be that `__array_wrap__` needs to be implemented, which I've done. Also, `np.extract` and `np.min` both return subclasses as expected, it's just when using `apply_along_axis` that I see this behavior.

Is there any way to get my code to return my subclass? 
I am using numpy version 1.11.0

Comment: This should be fixed in numpy 1.13, and as of https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/8441, will also call `__array_prepare__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `apply_along_axis` code (via Ipython ??)

```
Type:        function
String form: <function apply_along_axis at 0xb5a73b6c>
File:        /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/shape_base.py
Definition:  np.apply_along_axis(func1d, axis, arr, *args, **kwargs)
Source:
def apply_along_axis(func1d, axis, arr, *args, **kwargs):
...
    outarr = zeros(outshape, asarray(res).dtype)
    outarr[tuple(ind)] = res
....
    return outarr
```

I skipped a lot of details, but basically it uses `np.zeros` with `shape` and `dtype`, but makes no effort to adjust for array subclass.

Many numpy functions delegate the action to the method of the array, or use  `_wrapit` (`_wrapit(a, 'take', indices, axis, out, mode)`).

Do you really need to use `apply_along_axis`?  There's nothing magical about it.  You can do the same iteration in your own code, and just as fast.

===================

Here are the 2 `apply_along_axis` examples, and alternative implementations.  They are too small for meaningful timings, I'm sure they are just as fast, if not more so:

```
In [3]: def my_func(a):
    return (a[0]+a[-1]*0.5)    
In [4]: b=np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)

In [5]: np.apply_along_axis(my_func,0,b)
Out[5]: array([ 4.5,  6. ,  7.5])

In [6]: np.apply_along_axis(my_func,1,b)
Out[6]: array([  2.5,   7. ,  11.5])
```

Direct array implementation:

```
In [8]: b[0,:]+b[-1,:]*0.5
Out[8]: array([ 4.5,  6. ,  7.5])

In [9]: b[:,0]+b[:,-1]*0.5
Out[9]: array([  2.5,   7. ,  11.5])
```

2nd:

```
In [10]: c=np.array([[8,1,7],[4,3,9],[5,2,6]])

In [11]: np.apply_along_axis(sorted, 1, c)
Out[11]: 
array([[1, 7, 8],
       [3, 4, 9],
       [2, 5, 6]])

In [12]: d=np.zeros_like(c)
In [13]: for i in range(c.shape[0]):
   ....:     d[i,:] = sorted(c[i,:]) 

In [14]: d
Out[14]: 
array([[1, 7, 8],
       [3, 4, 9],
       [2, 5, 6]])
```

In the first I skip the iteration entirely; in the 2nd I use the same allocate and iterate, with less overhead.

Look at `np.matrix` and `np.ma` for examples of how `ndarray` subclasses are implemented.

---

`np.core.fromnumeric.py` as a `_wrapit` function that is used by functions like `np.take`:

```
# functions that are now methods
def _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds):
    try:
        wrap = obj.__array_wrap__
    except AttributeError:
        wrap = None
    result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
    if wrap:
        if not isinstance(result, mu.ndarray):
            result = asarray(result)
        result = wrap(result)
    return result
```

So it appears that if `obj` has a `__array_wrap__` method, it will apply that to the array result.  So you might be able to use that as a model for wrapping `apply_along_axis` to get back your own class.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I was curious if there was any good design reason apply_along_axis didn't return a subclass, and it looks like the only one is convenience. Perhaps I can patch it. 

Although, you're right, I don't need that function. Even in my example, I could just use the axis argument to `min()`

Comment: It's possible that this function was written at a time when use of subclasses wasn't important.  `np.matrix` has been around a long time, but it is only 2d.  And `np.ma` usually needs to use its own funcitons/methods.  But look at `np.kron` in `np.lib.shape_base.py`.  It uses `asanyarray`, `subok` and a couple of custom `wrap` functions.